# UserInfoProvider.DeleteUser() vs DeleteData(whereCondition)

Tags: kentico

I know that `DeleteUser()` will run procedures to delete all relationships etc. Will the private internal `DeleteData` with a where condition also delete all relationships or will it just try deleting the main record from the table? If any relational data exists will it throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `UserInfoProvider.DeleteData()` it won't delete the related data. It just executes the object's deletion SQL query. It won't even look for the `cms.user.removedependencies` query.

On the other hand, calling `DeleteData()` upon an info object would cause the related data to be deleted.

If you need to bulk delete users then retrieve them from the DB using object query (make sure you restrict columns, `UserID` should be enough) first. And then iterate through the collection calling `Delete()` on each one of them.

```c#
foreach (var user in UserInfoProvider.GetUsers().Where("UserEnabled=0").Columns("UserID").TypedResult.Items)
{
    user.Delete();
}
```